# Colorbox plugin loading two instances of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Let me preface this by saying I am a rank newbie to jQuery and programming of any sort, so I will be slower on the uptake.

Before I start, I am using this plugin (http://3.s3.envato.com/files/36161092/index.html#/homepage) to serve pages within a frame of a parent html page.

The problem is that I have two pages with Colorbox galleries. I can load up the first gallery with no problem. However, if I go to a second page with a Colorbox gallery and load an image up from its gallery, there are two instances of the Colorbox loading up at once. So the user has to click twice to get out of the Colorbox window.

Within the context of the third party plugin I've detailed above, is there a way to stop this from happening? (Colorbox works fine when I take the Revolver plugin out of the mix and I link and load them up by themselves).

This is the code I am using on one page -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gallery1").colorbox({rel:"gallery1", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery2").colorbox({rel:"gallery2", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery3").colorbox({rel:"gallery3", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery4").colorbox({rel:"gallery4", transition:"fade" });
});
```

The code I am using on the 2nd page is the basically the same, but its just the gallery names are changed for sequence's sake.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gallery5").colorbox({rel:"gallery5", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery6").colorbox({rel:"gallery6", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery7").colorbox({rel:"gallery7", transition:"fade" });
$(".gallery8").colorbox({rel:"gallery8", transition:"fade" });
});
```

Is there a way to refresh the instance of Colorbox when loading the second page or somehow load Colorbox so that it will apply to both pages without messing up as I've described?

I've looked up the issue on StackOverflow and this is the closest I could get to my own problem. [jQuery colorbox loading 2 iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434722/jquery-colorbox-loading-2-iframes). The solution presented does not quite work for me. I know there is something there that I can adapt with using .load perhaps, but I am not sure how to use it in my context.  I've tried adapting what the solution was there (it works somewhat), but it always loads the first slide, no matter what picture in the gallery I choose.

Anyway, this is my shot in the dark. Sorry for the long explanation and thank you in advance for any assistance the peeps out on the interwebs can render.

Comment: you're missing a quotation on both of those: `$(".gallery8").colorbox({rel:'gallery8, transition:"fade" });` right after `gallery8` and `gallery4`

Comment: Oops...thanks for pointing that out.  I've corrected that and I've changed the single quotes to double for consistencies sake.  Anyway, problem is still up for solving.

Comment: I'll have to check this out again a little later but in the meantime, if you're using that page slider plugin, then I'm guessing you'd appreciate my new favorite site.  Click through all the "Playground" items and check each demo.  You won't be disappointed :) http://tympanus.net/codrops/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved this.  Not sure its the most elegant way, but it works for me.

The parent html document in the Revolver plugin that loads external html content is already calling for jQuery to load.  When the external documents get loaded in upon user input, the external pages were loading jQuery on top of jQuery.  However, when I removed the jQuery call from these external pages, they lost Colorbox functionality.  Since I need jQuery to execute Colorbox and other jQuery dependent plugins on these external pages, I had to find a way to load it again without interfering with the parent html page's copy of it.

Since my homepage content was initially in a div, I changed it to be another external page to be loaded up.  In my parent html , I used this script:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#your_content").load("your_home_page.html"); 
}); 
</script>
```

And then in my parent HTML , I created a div:

```
<div id="your_content"></div>
```

In the "your_home_page.html" I called up jQuery.  Any other existing external pages that require jQuery do not need to have it be called again the code.  Loading it up initially in the first page content allows you to use Colorbox on multiple externally loaded pages, without having it load up twice when a user clicks on a Colorbox thumbnail.  I am sure this will resolve conflicts for other jQuery plugins beyond just Colorbox that are being used in tandem with plugins like Revolver.